# Prevent Google Docs Form Redirect on Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, google-docs, magnific-popup

I used this method to redirect google docs forms to redirect to custom page. (source : morning.am)

```
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>

<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='REDIRECT-URL.html';}"></iframe>

<form action="GOOGLE-SPREADSHEET-LINK" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
```

But I do not want it to redirect to any page. Instead show a confirmation message in a popup div (like Magnific Popup - inline).

Comment: I figured it out that i can avoid the redirection by removing {window.location='REDIRECT-URL.html';} from the iframe.
but still i want to know how to open a magnific popup (inline div) on submit that shows "your view submitted"